# Should observations be treated as answers?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing Late Answers when I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548353/finding-max-possible-date-in-ms-sql-server-2005/26394544#26394544) answer which is more like an observation made when using the code already mentioned in an the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/548373/2246380) for the same question. As it is not an answer more like a comment made on the accepted answer or a separate question altogether hence I flagged the answer as `not an answer` and got the following response

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

So from now on should I stop flagging answers like these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the same answer as well, and almost put a "not an answer" flag on it. Particularly the "I get these odd results" part initially made me think it was a "I'm having this problem too" answer, or a "different question".

After having a closer look at the question and answer, I decided not to flag it. My reasoning was:

- It answers the question. It provides the maximum possible date, which is what the OP asked for.
- It uses data to support the answer, which is a really positive aspect.
- It points out a subtle aspect suggesting that the result is not exactly what one would expect based on the information in the manual. Granted, it does not sound very significant, but there is at least an *attempt* to provide additional information.

Your observation that it has a lot of overlap with other answers is absolutely right. But that alone is not a reason to get it deleted.

Overall, in my opinion, it's not a very good answer. But I agree with the moderator that it does not meet the criteria for deletion.

I don't think flagging it was a bad mistake, though. This answer did look very similar to other answers that should be flagged. If you flag regularly, and this declined flag is a rare occurrence, you're most likely applying reasonable judgment. If you get your flags declined on a regular basis, you have more reason to believe that your criteria are not aligned with the ones used by the moderators.

As always, you can of course downvote the post if you feel that it does not provide value.

Comment: I agree with your points especially the subtle aspect part. I was under the impression that the user not having the required rep to comment under the accepted answer might have added it as answer. I have been reviewing the Late Answers and First posts from the last week where I see many new users adding answers for comments.I do come across cases like these where the user contributes little to post with an answer which is best suited as a comment hence I have been flagging them as not an answer. This is first declined flag after I started reviewing.

Comment: I am under the impression if a answer is suited as a comment,  I should flag it `not an answer` and the moderator might convert the answer to a comment. I feel this would be apt as comment on the accepted answer instead of a new answer.

Comment: voting up not because I agree with your assessment but because you achieved it using the **200% correct way: "having a closer look at the question and answer"**. Wish more LQ reviewers do so - with limit of 20 reviews a day they have plenty time for that